# Compiling hamcrest fails

Tags: erlang, xmpp

I'm compiling the `escalus` XMPP client

But everything goes well with `rebar3` until it compiles hamcrest, it throws me this error:

```
===> Compiling hamcrest
===> Compiling _build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl failed
_build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl:59: syntax error before: '/'
_build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl:63: syntax error before: '/'
_build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl:67: syntax error before: '/'
_build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl:72: syntax error before: '/'
_build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl:79: syntax error before: '/'
_build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl:90: syntax error before: '/'
_build/default/lib/hamcrest/src/hamcrest.erl:108: syntax error before: '/'
```

I don't get it, this is one of the lines causing the error:

```
-spec(is_matcher/1 :: (any()) -> boolean()).
is_matcher(Something) ->
erlang:is_record(Something, 'hamcrest.matchspec').
```

Seems like `is_matcher` is causing this, or even this another one

```
-spec(match/2 :: (term(), matchspec()) -> boolean()).
match(Value, MatchSpec) ->
match(Value, MatchSpec, fun() -> ok end).
```

Is `match` in this case

I'm very new to this application, and fairly new to Erlang, so

Has anybody encounter this issue before?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Switch to master your hamcrest in [wsecli](https://github.com/esl/wsecli/blob/master/rebar.config) config. See [b572c39](https://github.com/hyperthunk/hamcrest-erlang/commit/b572c398189072d7fcb59d393a0763200a15c65d)

Comment: @Lol4t0 why not write your answer as an answer instead of a comment?